# How to clear what's inside a Text Widget when the user presses a new number in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

```
text = ""

e = Text(window, width = 15, height = 2, font = ("Times New Roman", 24))
e.grid(column = 0, row = 0, columnspan=5)

def show_value(val): # Displays the text when user clicks buttons
    global text
    text+=str(val)
    e.insert(END, val)
    
def clear(): # Clears what's inside the text frame
    global text
    e.delete("1.0", "end")
    text = ""

def delete(): # Deletes the last value/character
    e.delete("end-2c") 

def equal(): # Computes
    global text
    try:
        text = str(eval(text))
        e.delete("1.0", "end")
        e.insert("1.0", text)
    except:
        clear()
        e.insert("1.0", "Error")

#Buttons

# button_negative = Button(window, text = "+/-", width = 6, font = ("Arial", 10)) # ADD THIS SOON
button_zero = Button(window, text = "0", width = 6, font = ("Arial", 10), bg = "black", fg = "white", command = lambda: show_value(0))
button_one = Button(window, text = "1", width = 6, font = ("Arial", 10), bg = "black", fg = "white", command = lambda: show_value(1))
button_two = Button(window, text = "2", width = 6, font = ("Arial", 10), bg = "black", fg = "white", command = lambda: show_value(2))
button_three = Button(window, text = "3", width = 6, font = ("Arial", 10), bg = "black", fg = "white", command = lambda: show_value(3))
button_four = Button(window, text = "4", width = 6, font = ("Arial", 10), bg = "black", fg = "white", command = lambda: show_value(4))
button_five = Button(window, text = "5", width = 6, font = ("Arial", 10), bg = "black", fg = "white", command = lambda: show_value(5))
button_six = Button(window, text = "6", width = 6, font = ("Arial", 10), bg = "black", fg = "white", command = lambda: show_value(6))
button_seven = Button(window, text = "7", width = 6, font = ("Arial", 10), bg = "black", fg = "white", command = lambda: show_value(7))
button_eight = Button(window, text = "8", width = 6, font = ("Arial", 10), bg = "black", fg = "white", command = lambda: show_value(8))
button_nine = Button(window, text = "9", width = 6, font = ("Arial", 10), bg = "black", fg = "white", command = lambda: show_value(9))
button_equals = Button(window, text = "=", width = 6, font = ("Arial", 10), bg = "#7C3D00", fg = "white", command = equal)
button_decimal = Button(window, text = ".", width = 6, font = ("Arial", 10), bg = "black", fg = "white", command = lambda: show_value("."))
button_add = Button(window, text = "+", width = 6, font = ("Arial", 10), bg = "black", fg = "white", command = lambda: show_value("+"))
button_subtract = Button(window, text = "-", width = 6, font = ("Arial", 10), bg = "black", fg = "white", command = lambda: show_value("-"))
button_divide = Button(window, text = "/", width = 6, font = ("Arial", 10), bg = "black", fg = "white", command = lambda: show_value("/"))
button_multiply = Button(window, text = "*", width = 6, font = ("Arial", 10), bg = "black", fg = "white", command = lambda: show_value("*"))
button_clear = Button(window, text = "AC", width = 6, font = ("Arial", 10), bg = "black", fg = "white", command = clear)
button_delete = Button(window, text = "DEL", width = 6, font = ("Arial", 10), bg = "black", fg = "white", command = delete)
button_left_bracket = Button(window, text = "(", width = 6, font = ("Arial", 10), bg = "black", fg = "white", command = lambda: show_value("("))
button_right_bracket = Button(window, text = ")", width = 6, font = ("Arial", 10), bg = "black", fg = "white", command = lambda: show_value(")"))

#button_negative.grid(row = 7, column = 0)
button_zero.grid(row = 7, column = 0)
button_decimal.grid(row = 7, column = 1)
button_equals.grid(row = 7, column = 3)
button_delete.grid(row = 7, column = 2)

button_one.grid(row = 5, column = 0)
button_two.grid(row = 5, column = 1)
button_three.grid(row = 5, column = 2)
button_add.grid(row = 5, column = 3)

button_four.grid(row = 4, column = 0)
button_five.grid(row = 4, column = 1)
button_six.grid(row = 4, column = 2)
button_subtract.grid(row = 4, column = 3)

button_seven.grid(row = 3, column = 0)
button_eight.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
button_nine.grid(row = 3, column = 2)
button_multiply.grid(row = 3, column = 3)

button_clear.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
button_left_bracket.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
button_right_bracket.grid(row = 2, column = 2)
button_divide.grid(row = 2, column = 3)

window.mainloop()
```

I'm still learning Python and wanted to create a Calculator as my first project. My issue is, when the user wants to compute 8 + 8 and clicks on the equals button, it displays 16. However, I want it to be cleared without pressing the all clear button when the user wants to calculate something new e.g 56 + 6 and displays that instead. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@sramazoth [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72656183/355230) is the right basic idea, but unfortunately the way your code is written it won't work if the user is using the keyboard to enter values (and not just the displayed calculator's buttons). The problem is due to the use of that global `text` variable being used. Your attempt to make its contents be the same as what is in the `Text` only works for clicking on the `Button`s being displayed, but it's also possible for a user to directly enter values into the `Text` widget via the *keyboard*, which will not be detected by your code.

I corrected the issue by doing two things (in addition to adding a `global` flag like @sramazoth suggested):

1. Eliminating the `global text` string variable completely — there's really no need for it since the text you need is already being stored in the `Text` widget itself.
2. Added a keypress event handler and bound it to the `Text` widget which will set the global flag just like clicking on one of the buttons to enter a value would.

You also need to understand that applying `eval()` to untrusted user input is a severe security hazard because they can enter arbitrary code that can do bad things.

Given that caveat, here's the modified code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter.constants import *

clear_flag = False  # Indicates when Text widget should be cleared.

window = tk.Tk()

e = tk.Text(window, width=15, height=2, font=("Times New Roman", 24))
e.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=5)


def on_keypress(event):
    global clear_flag
    if clear_flag:
        clear()
        clear_flag = False

e.bind('<KeyPress>', on_keypress)

def show_value(val): # Displays the expression when user clicks buttons
    global clear_flag
    if clear_flag:
        clear()
        clear_flag = False
    e.insert(END, val)

def clear(): # Clears what's inside the expression frame
    e.delete("1.0", "end")

def delete(): # Deletes the last value/character
    e.delete("end-2c")

def equal(): # Computes
    global clear_flag
    try:
        result = eval(e.get("1.0", END))
        e.delete("1.0", "end")
        e.insert("1.0", result)
    except Exception as exc:
        clear()
        e.insert("1.0", "Error")
    clear_flag = True

#Buttons

# button_negative = tk.Button(window, text="+/-", width=6, font=("Arial", 10)) # ADD THIS SOON
button_zero = tk.Button(window, text="0", width=6, font=("Arial", 10), bg="black", fg="white", command=lambda: show_value(0))
button_one = tk.Button(window, text="1", width=6, font=("Arial", 10), bg="black", fg="white", command=lambda: show_value(1))
button_two = tk.Button(window, text="2", width=6, font=("Arial", 10), bg="black", fg="white", command=lambda: show_value(2))
button_three = tk.Button(window, text="3", width=6, font=("Arial", 10), bg="black", fg="white", command=lambda: show_value(3))
button_four = tk.Button(window, text="4", width=6, font=("Arial", 10), bg="black", fg="white", command=lambda: show_value(4))
button_five = tk.Button(window, text="5", width=6, font=("Arial", 10), bg="black", fg="white", command=lambda: show_value(5))
button_six = tk.Button(window, text="6", width=6, font=("Arial", 10), bg="black", fg="white", command=lambda: show_value(6))
button_seven = tk.Button(window, text="7", width=6, font=("Arial", 10), bg="black", fg="white", command=lambda: show_value(7))
button_eight = tk.Button(window, text="8", width=6, font=("Arial", 10), bg="black", fg="white", command=lambda: show_value(8))
button_nine = tk.Button(window, text="9", width=6, font=("Arial", 10), bg="black", fg="white", command=lambda: show_value(9))
button_equals = tk.Button(window, text="=", width=6, font=("Arial", 10), bg="#7C3D00", fg="white", command=equal)
button_decimal = tk.Button(window, text=".", width=6, font=("Arial", 10), bg="black", fg="white", command=lambda: show_value("."))
button_add = tk.Button(window, text="+", width=6, font=("Arial", 10), bg="black", fg="white", command=lambda: show_value("+"))
button_subtract = tk.Button(window, text="-", width=6, font=("Arial", 10), bg="black", fg="white", command=lambda: show_value("-"))
button_divide = tk.Button(window, text="/", width=6, font=("Arial", 10), bg="black", fg="white", command=lambda: show_value("/"))
button_multiply = tk.Button(window, text="*", width=6, font=("Arial", 10), bg="black", fg="white", command=lambda: show_value("*"))

button_clear = tk.Button(window, text="AC", width=6, font=("Arial", 10), bg="black", fg="white", command=clear)
button_delete = tk.Button(window, text="DEL", width=6, font=("Arial", 10), bg="black", fg="white", command=delete)

button_left_bracket = tk.Button(window, text="(", width=6, font=("Arial", 10), bg="black", fg="white", command=lambda: show_value("("))
button_right_bracket=tk.Button(window, text=")", width=6, font=("Arial", 10), bg="black", fg="white", command=lambda: show_value(")"))

#button_negative.grid(row = 7, column = 0)
button_zero.grid(row = 7, column = 0)
button_decimal.grid(row = 7, column = 1)
button_equals.grid(row = 7, column = 3)
button_delete.grid(row = 7, column = 2)

button_one.grid(row = 5, column = 0)
button_two.grid(row = 5, column = 1)
button_three.grid(row = 5, column = 2)
button_add.grid(row = 5, column = 3)

button_four.grid(row = 4, column = 0)
button_five.grid(row = 4, column = 1)
button_six.grid(row = 4, column = 2)
button_subtract.grid(row = 4, column = 3)

button_seven.grid(row = 3, column = 0)
button_eight.grid(row = 3, column = 1)
button_nine.grid(row = 3, column = 2)
button_multiply.grid(row = 3, column = 3)

button_clear.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
button_left_bracket.grid(row = 2, column = 1)
button_right_bracket.grid(row = 2, column = 2)
button_divide.grid(row = 2, column = 3)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hi there. Thank you so much for this. I wasn't sure if you read my message before I deleted it, but I now understand how the clear_flag works. Thank you very much

Comment: I was writing a reply to it before you deleted it, so I'll post it anyway: It's fine to ask for further information about an answer down here in a comment. The logic behind the flag is that the `equals()` function sets it to `True` whenever it called — because that changes the contents of the `Text` widget with the result of evaluating it — to indicate to that the widget needs to be cleared before any new stuff is put into it. In the same code, the `show_value()` and `on_keypress()` functions do this, so they both check the flag (and reset if after being called).

Answer (score 1):

When manipulating GUI like tkinter, I recommend you to use Python classes, as it will be easier to manipulate elements.

As for your problem, does something like this suits your needs ?

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import tkinter as tk

text = ""

CALCUL_DONE=False

window=tk.Tk()

e = tk.Text(window, width = 15, height = 2, font = ("Times New Roman", 24))
e.grid(column = 0, row = 0, columnspan=5)

def clear(): # Clears what's inside the text frame
    global text
    e.delete("1.0", "end")
    text = ""

def show_value(val): # Displays the text when user clicks buttons
    global text, CALCUL_DONE
    if CALCUL_DONE:
        clear()
        CALCUL_DONE=False
    text+=str(val)
    e.insert(tk.END, val)
    

def delete(): # Deletes the last value/character
    e.delete("end-2c") 

def equal(): # Computes
    global text, CALCUL_DONE
    try:
        text = str(eval(text))
        e.delete("1.0", "end")
        e.insert("1.0", text)
        CALCUL_DONE=True
    except:
        clear()
        e.insert("1.0", "Error")

#Buttons

# button_negative = tk.Button(window, text = "+/-", width = 6, font = ("Arial", 10)) # ADD THIS SOON
button_zero = tk.Button(window, text = "0", width = 6, font = ("Arial", 10), bg = "black", fg = "white", command = lambda: show_value(0))

[...]

button_right_bracket = tk.Button(window, text = ")", width = 6, font = ("Arial", 10), bg = "black", fg = "white", command = lambda: show_value(")"))

#button_negative.grid(row = 7, column = 0)
button_zero.grid(row = 7, column = 0)

[...]

button_divide.grid(row = 2, column = 3)

window.mainloop()
```

I added a boolean (CALCUL_DONE) initialized at False, so when you click on "+","-",... it changes its value to True, and when clicking on a number again, the funtion clear() is called.